# Font size to fill dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, font-size

I'm trying to get font size to adjust to fill a container. This alone obviously is not an issue. However, the container is also not a static size, it's size is set to a % of the browser window and I would like the font size to dynamically update on browser resizing, along with the container.

I had been using a modified script that I found which adjusts the font size by a % of the browser height and width.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var $body = $('body'); //Cache this for performance

    var setBodyScale = function() {
        var scaleFactor = 0.0001,
            scaleSource = $(window).height(),
            scaleSource2 = $(window).width(),
            maxScale = 200,
            minScale = 10;

        var fontSize = (scaleSource * scaleSource2) * scaleFactor; //Multiply the width of the body by the scaling factor:

        if (fontSize > maxScale) fontSize = maxScale;
        if (fontSize < minScale) fontSize = minScale; //Enforce the minimum and maximums

        $('body').css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setBodyScale();
    });

    //Fire it when the page first loads:
    setBodyScale();
});
```

I wasnt getting the desired result from this, so then tried changing this so that the scale sources were the container rather than the window. This somewhat worked however it didnt dynamically update, it would require a refresh of the page.

In short I cannot find a way to resize font size, to fill a container that's size is determined by a % of the browser window, on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Why invent something that already exists? There's already a great jQuery tool out there: http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: This only resizes to the width of a container. I want the font size to adjust to the size of the container whether its the width or height changing.

Comment: You could try contacting the makers of this script. They are on Twitter! https://twitter.com/#!/trentwalton http://twitter.com/davatron5000 http://twitter.com/raygunray

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real-world answer, yet, but viewport dependent font sizes are on the horizon:

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Currently it's only supported in Chrome Canary, but it's good to know it's coming.